# Creating tests to maintain minimum coverage?

Tags: python, code-coverage, python-unittest, coverage.py

Is there a way to create a Makefile/script that will fail if a file from coverage.py library has values below a certain threshold? Say 80%.

Comment: It is not unit-test task to control the coverage threshold. Usually this aspect is being controlled by code quality tools like Sonar Qube and integrated into CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: That's not really something you would do in a unit test (because you can't calculate coverage until *after* your units tests have finished executing). You can certainly implement a post-unittest check for coverage changes (for example, if you're using a higher level test harness like [tox](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/)), or as part of a CI pipeline (like a GitHub workflow). Online coverage tests (like [Codecov](https://about.codecov.io/)) offer this functionality "out of the box".

Answer (score 1):

For coverage.py you can use [`fail_under`](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.4/config.html#report-fail-under) option

First, gather test coverage by using the coverage run command ([here](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.4/index.html#quick-start)), then run the coverage report command

### Option 1.

Run via coverage report command directly

```bash
coverage report --fail-under=80
```

### Option 2.

Use configuration file by defining value in the report section of .coveragerc

```ini
[report]
fail_under = 80
```

Then run the coverage report command

```bash
coverage report
```

It will return non zero exit code if the coverage is below the value of `fail_under`

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more fine-grained than an overall percentage threshold, you can try this coverage goals program I threw together: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202111/coverage_goals.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the following. Feel free to copy if it fits your needs!

The Makefile goes as follows:

```
test: $(TEST_DIRECTORY)/*/*
    rm -f $(TEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)/coverage_tests.log
    cd $(TEST_DIRECTORY)/inference && coverage run -m unittest discover
    for file in $^ ; do \
        TEST_FILE=$$(echo $${file} | grep -E -o test_.*) ; \
        FILE=$$(echo $${TEST_FILE} | sed 's/test_//') ; \
        if [[ ! -z $${FILE} ]] ; then \
            cd $(TEST_DIRECTORY)/inference && coverage report --include $(INFERENCE_DIRECTORY)/$${FILE} > $(TEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)/coverage_temp.log ; \
            cd $(TEST_DIRECTORY) && ./coverage_check.sh $${FILE} < $(TEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)/coverage_temp.log >> $(TEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)/coverage_tests.log ; \
            rm -f $(TEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)/coverage_temp.log ; \
        fi ; \
    done
    rm -f $(TEST_DIRECTORY)/inference/.coverage
```

and it utilizes a coverage check script which is here:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line; do
    for word in $line; do
        if [[ "$word" == *"%"* ]]; then
            COVERAGE=`echo $word | sed 's/%//g'`
            if [ $COVERAGE -gt 80 ]
                then
                echo "$1: PASSED $word"
                break 2
                else
                echo "$1: FAILED $word"
                break 2
            fi
        fi
    done
done
```